Zoom communication restrictions between departments
As the software expert of my company my boss has asked me if there is a way where zoom groups can be made that represents departments of the company and only the head of each department can talk to other heads of departments. The HR should be able to communicate with the rest of the departments the employees in those departments should only be able top talk to each other in said group. IF you ask me it looks like he wants to make an custom app of Zoom  can anybody help me answer this question to him if its possible or not ?
I've already tried doing my own research and what i've come to find it is that i can't make any restrictions on that level i can make private channels and put those departments name as the private channel's name but furthermore i can't find anything that can restrict the employees from communicating with the rest of the company. I've also tried to put the employees in user groups
https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0062584#:~:text=Groups%20allow%20you%20to%20turn,click%20User%20Management%20then%20Groups.
https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0066764
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QpXaQi5Pas0
https://support.zoom.com/hc/en/article?id=zm_kb&sysparm_article=KB0064983

Hey @Team Software, can you clarify if you are referring to Zoom Meetings, Zoom Team Chat, or a custom video experience like Zoom Video SDK? Might I suggest posting on the Zoom community: https://community.zoom.com/

Hey i've posted this question in the zoom community as well and for clarification the Zooms team chat
